# Create a MongoDB database through docker-compose

Tags: mongodb, docker-compose

docker-compose.yml

```
mongo:
        image: mongo:3.4.13-jessie
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "27019:27017"
        volumes:
            - ./db1.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/db1.js:ro
            - ./db2.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/db2.js:ro
```

db1.js

```
use testdba;
db.getCollection("users").insert({
   "name": "A"
})
```

db2.js

```
use testdbb;
db.getCollection("users").insert({
   "name": "B"
})
```

the files are copied in the mongo container but not executed 
my understanding is that files(*.js) inside `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` gets executed, but with above setup it doesn't

does anyone know what am I missing?

also in some of the post I found

```
environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: test
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: admin
```

do I need to add root user before the .js fils can be executed ?

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB finds your files and tries to execute them but it fails. You can see that in the logs: `docker-compose logs -f` and look for the line where it tries to run your first js file.

To fix it use this syntax in your js files:

```js
db.testdba.getCollection("users").insert({
   "name": "A"
});
```

After you edit both your files start your service with `docker-compose up -d`. Check again the logs and you will see that the files are executed successfully.